# How to automatically change relative cell formula in excel after deleting columns in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to delete some columns in excel and need cell formula getting automatically updated with reference to new column.

I have large sets of data, each in an excel column like below.

```
    A   B   C   D
1   Set1    Set2    Set3    Set4
2   100 140 70  90
3   220 70  520 70
4   270 450 520 490
5   -50 240 -70 330
```

in the data above, 5th row comes from formula `=A4-A2-A3`.

I want to delete Set1 and Set3 for some reason.

I used below code using `openpyxl`.

```
delete_col_list=[1,3]
for i in range(len(delete_col_list)):
    sheet.delete_cols(delete_col_list[i])
```

This code is deleting the columns. However, it is not updating the formula in row 5. Set2 is now in column A but 5th row still shows `=B4-B2-B3`. Similarly, Set2 is now in column B but 5th row still shows `=D4-D2-D3`.

I need to update Set2 formula to `=A4-A2-A3` and Set4 formula to `=B4-B2-B3` as per the new columns.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `OPENPYXL` at all so this can be all wrong, but isn't formulae translation disabled by default? So this is expected behaviour. See [this](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html)

Comment: You have to manage formula translation yourself, you can use the formula tokeniser in the library to do this.

Comment: If you have Excel (the program from Microsoft), it might be easier to automate that. The most straightforward thing to use for that is probably VBA, but if you want to stick with Python, you should try [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/).